# \hbar not displayed with fontspec on XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

With `\usepackage{fontspec}`, `\hbar` does not show up correctly. Tested on `LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5` and `fontspec.sty 2018/07/30 vv2.6h`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
[$\hbar$]
\end{document}
```

With LuaLaTeX:
[image: hbar-lualatex]

With XeLaTeX:

[image: hbar-xelatex]

I found that

- Adding `\usepackage{unicode-math}`

or

- `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`

can resolve this problem, but I'm not sure which is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of hbar is quite encoding dependant. As fontspec changes the operator font it breaks.

You could redefine it if you don't want to switch to unicode-math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}

\def\hbar{{\mathchar175\mkern-9muh}}
[$\hbar$]

\def\hbar{\mathit{^^^^0127}}

[$\hbar$]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but why fontspec does not give that kind of redefinition? Accents (\grave, \acute, \bar etc.) are all handled specially so that operators font is always used, according to fontspec-math.dtx...

Comment: Perhaps Will overlooked it. Open an issue at the github page.

Comment: Done https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/337

Answer (score 2):

The character used for the bar in legacy math fonts has a different code in Unicode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\renewcommand{\hbar}{{\mathchar"AF\mkern-9mu h}}

\begin{document}

[$h$]

[$\hbar$]

\sbox0{$h$}\the\wd0

\sbox0{$\hbar$}\the\wd0

\end{document}
```

[image]

The difference in width is slightly more than 0.00004 millimeters, less than the difference with `pdflatex`. The bar is a bit higher, though.

The standard definition for `\hbar` is

```
\def\hbar{{\mathchar'26\mkern-9muh}}
```

and `\mathchar'26` refers to the character in slot octal 26 (decimal 22) in math group 0 (the standard text font). This is the same character used for the macron accent, which in OpenType fonts is at slot `0xAF`. Depending on the font it can be higher or lower.

Note that Unicode has a special slot for the Planck constants

> U+201E PLANCK CONSTANT
>   U+201F PLANCK CONSTANT OVER TWO PI

and `unicode-math` will define `\hbar` to select the latter.